# Typescript - Higher order function types

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, typescript, higher-order-functions

I'm getting really excited about TypeScript. How do you set the type of a function parameter?

```
function twoMoreThanYou(calculateANumber: Function):number {
    return calculateANumber(4) + 2;
}

function double(n:number):number {
    return n*2;
}

console.log("TWO MORE", twoMoreThanYou(double))
```

How can I type `calculateANumber` better? I'd like to specify that it must be a function that takes a number and returns a number.

Can I then make an "interface" or some shorthand for that type so I can make my higher order function signatures more readable?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

These both work

```
interface NumberFunction extends Function {
    (n:number):number;
}

function twoMoreThanYou(calculateANumber: (n:number)=>number):number {
    ...
}

function twoMoreThanYou(calculateANumber: NumberFunction):number {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You don't have to specify the return type for the `twoMoreThanYou` function with the `NumberFunction` interface. Type inference!